# Scope not seeming to apply in MongoClient.connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, closures

I'm trying to pass a variable into a Mongo query like this:

```
function retrieveDocNumber( docNumber ) {
    MongoClient.connect( 'mongodb://' + this.mongoUrl + "/" + this.mongoDbName, function(error, db) {
        var lessonCollection = db.collection( 'lessons' );

        if ( error ) {
            console.log( error );
        } else {
            console.log( docNumber ) // Is undefined...
            lessonCollection.findOne( {number: docNumber}, function( error, doc ) {
                console.log( error );
                console.log( doc );
            } );
        }
    });
```

So I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but the docNumber (and any other variables not directly in the connect functions enclosing scope) are undefined in the connect function.  Any workarounds or obvious places where this is going wrong?  I need to retrieve a doc from the database using a user defined docNumber.

Comment: It doesnt look that the docNumber is manipulated anywhere in the retrieveDocNumber function. So the obvious thing would be to check the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, silly question, the answer was because the docNumber was incorrectly parsed into a string instead of an int...